# Exception `SocketError' getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

I started getting this error after upgrading to selenium-webdriver gem 2.22.1.

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

Basically the browser is not launched ( OSX  10.6.8, ruby 1.8.7 ) and a ruby debug mode showed the below output.

Exception `SocketError' at /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:153 - getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

I went through the similar issue reported here and tried the solutions such as making sure localhost entry is present in /etc/hosts and the port is not used up by any other processes etc.

Let me know any more info is required.

Comment: I went back to selenium-webdriver -v 2.21.2 and everything works. http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rb/CHANGES shows some changes made to finding free ports in version 2.22.0 which may have caused this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [this was a bug](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4020), and is now fixed in selenium-webdriver 2.22.2